# Android: Ошибка при выполнении POST запроса

Tags: android, json, eclipse, post

Добрый день. Второй день мучаюсь, не могу найти, в чем проблема. Хочу отправить POST запрос, получить ответ и обработать его. Выполняю все в отдельном потоке, почему не получается не ясно.

```
package com.example.response;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.Proxy;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;



import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button button1;
    private TextView info;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(button1Listener);
        info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public OnClickListener button1Listener = new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            DoPOST dp = new DoPOST();
            dp.doInBackground("http://www.forismatic.com/api/1.0/");
        }
    };
    private class DoPOST extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        @Override 
         protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            info.setText("Start");
        }
         @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
             super.onPostExecute(result);
             info.setText("All is right");
         }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {


                   String citateRequestString = "http://www.forismatic.com/api/1.0/";
                   String resultString = new String("");
                   try {

                       URLConnection connection = null;
                       URL url = new URL(citateRequestString);

                     // если используется прокси //
                        int portOfProxy = android.net.Proxy.getDefaultPort();
                        if( portOfProxy > 0 ){ 
                           Proxy proxyDef = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP,new InetSocketAddress( android.net.Proxy.getDefaultHost(), portOfProxy)); 
                             connection = url.openConnection(proxyDef);  
                      }
                      else 
                      {
                          connection = url.openConnection( );
                      }

                    /////////////////////////////





                     HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection)connection;
                     httpConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

                     httpConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "MyAndroid/1.6");
                     httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "ru-RU");
                     httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");


                     httpConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                     httpConnection.setDoInput(true);

                     httpConnection.connect();

                     // здесь можем писать в поток данные запроса
                     OutputStream os = httpConnection.getOutputStream();
                     String str = "method=getQuote&key=999&format=text&lang=ru";
                     os.write( str.getBytes()); 

                     os.flush();
                     os.close();


                      int responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();
                      if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                             InputStream in = httpConnection.getInputStream();

                             InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8");

                             StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer();
                             int c;
                             while ((c = isr.read()) != -1){
                                 data.append((char) c);
                             }


                             resultString = new String (data.toString());

                       }
                       else
                       {
                           resultString = "Server does not respond";
                       }
                    }
                    catch (MalformedURLException e) { 
                               resultString = "MalformedURLException:" + e.getMessage();
                      }
                    catch (IOException e) { 
                              resultString = "IOException:" + e.getMessage();
                     }

                    info.setText("resultString");
                    return resultString;


        }
    };


}
```

Логи:

```
03-02 09:33:31.577: D/dalvikvm(876): Late-enabling CheckJNI
03-02 09:33:32.198: W/ActivityThread(876): Application com.example.response is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
03-02 09:33:32.208: I/System.out(876): Sending WAIT chunk
03-02 09:33:33.579: I/dalvikvm(876): Debugger is active
03-02 09:33:33.609: I/System.out(876): Debugger has connected
03-02 09:33:33.609: I/System.out(876): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-02 09:33:33.809: I/System.out(876): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-02 09:33:34.009: I/System.out(876): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-02 09:33:34.210: I/System.out(876): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-02 09:33:34.410: I/System.out(876): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-02 09:33:34.610: I/System.out(876): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-02 09:33:34.810: I/System.out(876): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-02 09:33:35.010: I/System.out(876): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-02 09:33:35.211: I/System.out(876): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-02 09:33:35.411: I/System.out(876): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-02 09:33:35.611: I/System.out(876): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-02 09:33:35.821: I/System.out(876): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-02 09:33:36.021: I/System.out(876): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-02 09:33:36.222: I/System.out(876): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-02 09:33:36.422: I/System.out(876): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-02 09:33:36.632: I/System.out(876): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-02 09:33:36.832: I/System.out(876): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-02 09:33:37.032: I/System.out(876): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-02 09:33:37.233: I/System.out(876): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-02 09:33:37.433: I/System.out(876): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-02 09:33:37.633: I/System.out(876): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-02 09:33:37.833: I/System.out(876): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-02 09:33:38.033: I/System.out(876): waiting for debugger to settle...
03-02 09:33:38.234: I/System.out(876): debugger has settled (1473)
03-02 09:33:40.175: D/libEGL(876): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
03-02 09:33:40.195: D/libEGL(876): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
03-02 09:33:40.306: D/libEGL(876): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
03-02 09:33:40.306: D/libEGL(876): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
03-02 09:33:40.446: D/memalloc(876): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x520c9000 size:2088960 offset:0 fd:63
03-02 09:33:40.516: D/OpenGLRenderer(876): Enabling debug mode 0
03-02 09:33:41.146: D/memalloc(876): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x52676000 size:24997888 offset:22908928 fd:66
03-02 09:33:42.468: D/memalloc(876): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x53e4d000 size:27086848 offset:24997888 fd:69
03-02 09:33:42.558: D/AndroidRuntime(876): Shutting down VM
03-02 09:33:42.558: W/dalvikvm(876): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ab2228)
03-02 09:33:42.638: E/AndroidRuntime(876): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-02 09:33:42.638: E/AndroidRuntime(876): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
03-02 09:33:42.638: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1178)
03-02 09:33:42.638: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:394)
03-02 09:33:42.638: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:245)
03-02 09:33:42.638: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
03-02 09:33:42.638: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:71)
03-02 09:33:42.638: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
03-02 09:33:42.638: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
03-02 09:33:42.638: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
03-02 09:33:42.638: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
03-02 09:33:42.638: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
03-02 09:33:42.638: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:303)
03-02 09:33:42.638: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
03-02 09:33:42.638: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
03-02 09:33:42.638: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
03-02 09:33:42.638: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at com.example.response.MainActivity$DoPOST.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:116)
03-02 09:33:42.638: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at com.example.response.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:63)
03-02 09:33:42.638: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3549)
03-02 09:33:42.638: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14393)
03-02 09:33:42.638: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
03-02 09:33:42.638: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-02 09:33:42.638: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
03-02 09:33:42.638: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
03-02 09:33:42.638: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-02 09:33:42.638: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-02 09:33:42.638: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-02 09:33:42.638: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-02 09:33:42.638: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Тут таких вопросов уже было миллион. Почти русским языком называется эксэпшн android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException. Используйте AsyncTask

Comment: Да, вот один из них [Как получить запрос с сервера?](http://hashcode.ru/questions/142887/android-как-получить-запрос-с-сервера)

Comment: Спасибо, но ведь я и использую AsyncTask? За ссылку спасибо.

Comment: AsyncTask запускается по другому: .execute(), а не doInBackground()

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался! Очень помогли!!!